# Model Binding to an object with a collection

Tags: c#, html, razor, asp.net-mvc-5

I recently asked [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24504226/return-a-collection-of-models-from-a-view) about binding to a collection and got an answer that helped me a lot. Now, I have a new model that looks like this(trimmed version):

```
public class Order
{
    public int OrderId { get; set; }
    public string OrderName { get; set; }
    public string Comments { get; set; }

    public ICollection<OrderItems> OrderItems { get; set; }
}

public class OrderItems
{
    public int OrderItemId { get; set; }
    public int OrderId { get; set; }
    public string ItemName { get; set; }
}
```

So I want to have 2 `Inputs` for the `OrderName` and `Comments` and for the `OrderItems`
I dynamically create `Tables` with `Text Inputs`.
So if I use this syntax to `bind` to a collection:

```
<input type='text' name='OrderItem[1].ItemName'/>
```

how do I do it in a scenario where my collection is only one of the properties in my `Model`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

YOu can try this :

```
@model IList<CyberSystems.UI.Controllers.System.PurchaseOrderControllers.PurchaseOrderController.Order>
           @for (int i = 0; i < Model.Count; i++)
           {
               @Html.TextBoxFor(c=>Model[i].OrderName)

                   for (int ii = 0; ii < Model[i].OrderItems.Count; ii++)

                   {
                       @Html.TextBoxFor(c=>Model[i].OrderItems[@ii].ItemName)
                   }

           }
```